# What happens to two singular photons when their pilot waves cancel out?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

What happens to two singular photons when their pilot waves cancel out? Are those photons indeed particles and what happen to them in that case?

Comment: What explanations have you read or heard from instructors?

Comment: *Are those photons indeed particles?* They’re definitely not *classical* particles.

Comment: What you mean by saying "waves cancel out" ? Do you have in mind wave interference effect ? In such case, waves cancel each other out producing zero field in regions where one wave positive amplitude meets another wave negative amplitude. In QM view zero field areas are simply places where photon probability density is zero.

Comment: What is a singular photon?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Yes but a singular photon leaves only one dot on the screen, how we can possibly talk about waves only?The waves interfere all along the screen, the dot shows only at a certain point though at a position where waves are in constructive interference.

Comment: @garyp The photon that leaves only a discrete point on a detecting screen...